# Update raster data without restarting the service

Tags: raster, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to update raster datasets (3-4 times a day) that are being used by an ImageServer service.

Is there a way to do this without stopping/restarting the service (to get rid of possible locks) ?

PS: I am using ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 and the files are .tiff.